# Wood texture shows in material but not in rendered mode

Tags: modeling, rendering, light

I have a wood texture that's showing up fine in materials view but not in the rendered view. Can someone please tell me what I might be overlooking?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The image texture need to be connected to a diffuse shader node before going into the material surface output.

[image]

Comment: The output  of a texture node is color, as is the input of a diffuse shader. From my understanding, Blender needs inputs/ output types to match in order to work correctly.

Comment: @Marc.  How is primary. Why is secondary. You can just know the style above is correct.  Assume the BSDF in the name of the Diffuse BSDF makes it compatible in the chain of nodes.

Comment: For an object to be visible it needs to reflect, scatter, absorb or difuse, or emit light somehow. That is the role of shaders. A texture can be part of the attributes of a shader but does not define the behavior of a light ray.

Comment: And I might add ... the color dot at the input and output gives you a hint to what it should connect to. For example usually you will connect the yellow out to the yellow in and the green output to another green input. Just so when you are starting out with nodes just follow to color code.